# Finding source code for Nexus S Camera HAL?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-camera, android-source, nexus-s

I'm working on a project where I need to modify the driver for the Nexus S front facing Camera.  The driver source code is implemented in `drivers/media/video/s5ka3dfx.c`.  From looking at the driver implementation, it appears the driver is conforming to the V4L2 API.  However, it is unclear to me how the driver interfaces with the rest of the Android stack.  Somethere there needs to be a Hardware Abstraction Layer, containing the implementation of  the pure virtual CameraHardwareInterface class (which is declared in `platform_frameworks_base/include/CameraHardwareInterface.h`).

I have been unsuccessful in finding the source code for this Hardware Abstraction Layer.  http://android.git.kernel.org/ is dreaming of electric sheep at the moment, does anyone know of any alternative locations to find the source code for the Nexus S Camera HAL?

Comment: +1 for the cyberpunk reference, and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 5):

Follow Up: I downloaded a mirrored image of the Android platform code from https://www.codeaurora.org/gitweb/quic/la/.  Fortunately, the source code for the Camera HAL is located in `platforms/device/samsung/crespo/libcamera`.  `CameraHardwareInterface.h` is implemented in `SecCameraHWInterface.h`, and the V4L2 API is called from `SecCamera.cpp`.

For those looking for an explanation of every abstraction layer for the camera (from the hardware all the way up to the application layer), check out http://boundarydevices.com/blogs/camera-subsystem-overview-for-i-mx-gingerbread.